# On the orthogonal bases in $L^2[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, hilbert-spaces, fourier-series, orthogonal-polynomials

Let  $\{\phi_n\}$ be an orthonormal base in $L^2[0,1]$ such that for every **continuous functions**  $f$ on $[0,1]$ one may find a sequence of complex numbers $\{\lambda_n\}$ with $f(x)=\sum \lambda_n\phi_n(x)$ almost every where.

Q. Let $f$ be a continuous function. Does there exist a sequence of complex numbers $\{\mu_n\}$ such that $f(x)=\sum \mu_n\phi_n(x)$ **for every** $x\in [0,1]$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

We can redefine $\{\phi_n\}$ so that $\phi_n(1/2)=0$ for all $n$, which doesn't affect its property as an orthonormal basis of $L^2[0,1]$. This means that
$$
\sum \mu_n \phi_n(1/2) = 0
$$
for any sequence of complex number $\mu_n$, so it cannot be equal to any $f$ such that $f(1/2)\ne 0$.

Comment: @ BibbearZzz: Let us add one more assumption: Let $E$ be the linear space given by $\{\sum_1^n t_n\phi_n : n\in \mathbb{N}, t_n\in \mathbb{C}\}$. Suppose that the uniform closuer of $E$ is just $C[0,1]$. Does the claim valid now?

Comment: @AliBagheri Since this question is answered already, why don't you ask that in a separate question? I may have a look at it later.

Comment: Actually I don't quite understand your new question. Since you assumed that the uniform closure is $C[0,1]$, the statement that you want to prove follows by definition so there's nothing to prove.

Comment: I did not get how it is followed by definition.

Comment: @AliBagheri $f(x)=\sum \mu_n\phi_n(x)$ for all $x$ is pointwise convergence, but you're assuming something even stronger, i.e. uniform convergence of such sums to any $f\in C[0,1]$.

Comment: The second assumption says that there exists a sequence $\psi_n=\sum_{i=1}^n t_{i,n}\phi_n$ converging uniformly to $f$. How can I find $\{\mu_n\}$ to write $f=\sum\mu_n\phi_n$?

Comment: @AliBagheri Seems like I misunderstood you. Why don't you write a full question including all the details? I think it'd be easier to read that way.

Comment: OK. I  write a new one.